# Can you Nest "Onclicklisteners" in order to run multiple activities?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am creating this application, where I would like the user to click a certain button `photoButton` and have a new activity appear prompting the user for 2 edittext(entry) worth of information. I am getting an error in both cases:

1. When I try to start the activity and access the contents from the activity
2. When I open the activityforresult...,

I the click of one button to trigger both activities essentially.What exactly is returning a null value?

Attempt to use the `startactivityforresult` method..

```
   fun take_pic(){
        val takephotoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        if (takephotoIntent.resolveActivity(this.packageManager) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takephotoIntent, REQUESTCODE)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable To access Camera... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()
        }


    }
    fun display_information() {
        /* Connection to firebase       */
        val currentuser = auth.currentUser!!.email


        /* getting the values of the user*/
        val email_of_user = currentuser



        /* Changing the Displayed text                    */
        welcomemessagename.text = email_of_user
        Date.text = "Date:" + date_formatted
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_main_hub)
        val storageinfo = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/")

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        /* displaying basic information for the user comfort.        */
        display_information()

        audioscannerButton.setOnClickListener {
            val action = Intent(this, Recordinit::class.java)
            startActivity(action)
        }

        helpbutton.setOnClickListener {
            val action2 = Intent(this, HelpActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(action2)
        }
        photoButton.setOnClickListener {
            val action3 = Intent(this , nameofphoto::class.java)
            startActivityForResult(action3, REQUESTCODE2 )

        }
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (REQUESTCODE == requestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //Compressing the bitmap(image) into a byte[] to match the input of the .putbytes method
            val userimage = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
            val byteoutput = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            userimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100 , byteoutput)
            val data = byteoutput.toByteArray()
            //ref to the firebase "bucket" database
            val storageinfo = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/Images" )
            //extra data that shows who the images belong to (users)


           storageinfo.putBytes(data)


        }else if (requestCode ==REQUESTCODE2) {
            take_pic()

        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
        }



    }
```

the error now:

```
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 20616
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.User_main_hub$onCreate$3.onClick(User_main_hub.kt:82)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6618)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6590)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:781)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25950)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6952)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20616 SIG: 9
Process 20616 terminated.
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: check the description, I added some more information as to what exactly is wrong, and I provided the log of the run tab in android studio, it shows the error.@AlexMamo

Comment: You're accessing something null on line 82 `User_main_hub.kt:82`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reading between the lines, so not sure, but it looks like `metabtnsubmit` is not a member of the layout of this Activity, `R.layout.activity_user_main_hub`, so the synthetic getter fails to find it and returns `null`.

Maybe you were trying to set a click listener in the next activity that you're going to, "`nameofphoto`"? You cannot access its UI elements from this Activity.

Assuming it's an Activity that allows the user to enter text and select a photo, then you need to open it using `startActivityForResult`, have it set the data as its result, and respond to it in this Activity's `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: Can you show me how it would work with a few lines?

Comment: It's explained here. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

Comment: i am going to try to code this out to get a better understanding..

Comment: Looks like they very recently overhauled their recommended way of doing this. I haven't used `registerForActivityResult` before.

Comment: I used your method and still end up with the same problem..... take a look at the update..

Comment: What exactly is `nameofphoto`? Some nullable property? It should be the explicit name of an Activity subclass.

Comment: you got it brother

Comment: I’m baffled by it. The error says it’s null. A class name can’t be null. I was confused by that line because by convention all class names start with a capital letter. If you ctrl-click `nameofphoto` there, does it take you to its class definition?

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException occurs inside onClick, and the expression nameofphoto::class is distinct to others OnClick methods, thus, nameofphoto must to be the cause, in the source code you doesn´t show when nameofphoto is declared, or assigned.